# How to subsribe to a ROS topic for several seperate times?

Tags: python, ros, subscriber

I have a scanlist of 5 positions for the robot to go. And for each position, I hope to subscribe to a topic to get the sensor data and add a marker in the rviz. Here is my code:

```
def addMarkerCallback(msg):
    draw_functions = DrawFunctions('visualisation_marker')
    if msg.data:
        draw_functions.draw_rviz_sphere(0.02)
    else:
        print 'no data'

rospy.init_node("sensor_marker", anonymous = True)

for item in scanlist:    
    moveit_cmd.go(item, wait=True)
    sub1 = rospy.Subscriber('sensor/right', SensorData, addMarkerCallback)   
    rospy.spin()
    print 'go finished'
```

However when I run the code, the problem is the loop will always stay in the first iteration, so the robot will not go to the other positions in the scanlist. I guess it is the problem of rospy.spin(). Could anyone please tell me how to solve this problem...Thanks a lot!

Comment: Change `rospy.spin()` to `rospy.spinOnce()`. `spin()` takes over the control from Python.

Answer (score 0):

Using rospy.spin() means that python will not progress past that point, it gets caught (on purpose) in a loop by ROS.

The easiest short term solution is to move your rospy.spin() out of your for loop,
like so:

```
for item in scanlist:    
    moveit_cmd.go(item, wait=True)
    sub1 = rospy.Subscriber('sensor/right', SensorData, addMarkerCallback)   

print 'go finished'
rospy.spin()
```

In the longer term, think of what you are trying to do. In most cases, using a mix of publishing and subscribing is the best idea. Look at the ROS Python tutorials, especially the publisher example, again.

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(python)